# SweetAlert showLoaderOnConfirm not displaying

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

i am using sweetalert to display delete confirmation,and process it later while displayin a loading action,though it is not working,thi is the code,that doesn't work (it is supposed to display a loading animation,but it actually is not doing so) any thoughts ?

This the javascript

```
document.querySelector('div.test').onclick = function() {
swal({
title: 'Ajax request example',
text: 'Submit to run ajax request',
type: 'info',
showCancelButton: true,
closeOnConfirm: false,
showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
}, function(){
 setTimeout(function() {
  swal('Ajax request finished!');
}, 2000);
});
};
```

Html

```
<div class="test">
<button>show alert</button>
 </div>
```

this is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe096w10/283/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your include files are wrong (old for instance).

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('div.test').on('click', function (e) {
    swal({
      title: "Ajax request example",
      text: "Submit to run ajax request",
      type: "info",
      showCancelButton: true,
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
    }, function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        swal("Ajax request finished!");
      }, 2000);
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/t4t5/sweetalert/master/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
    <button>show alert</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank,you this did the trick,i did not know my includes were wrong,since it worked almost fine,though thank you for the hint(btw that jquery made a conflict with my datatables,so i simply didn't use it,am using my 1.12.3 jQuery) thanks for th hint saved me

Answer (score 5):

Sweetalert is unsupported anymore. You might want to switch to [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io):

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Ajax request example',
  text: 'Submit to run ajax request',
  icon: 'info',
  showCancelButton: true,
  showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
  preConfirm: function() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      // here should be AJAX request
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  },
}).then(function() {
  Swal.fire('Ajax request finished!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```